# Using a mixer with a PC and PS4

Tags: audio, mixer

I have been looking into using an audio mixer for my PS4 streaming. I am probably going to get a decent XLR microphone to use, and use this mixer, but need a little direction.

[http://www.amazon.com/Behringer-802-Premium-8-Input-Preamps/dp/B000J5XS3C/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1444774566&sr=1-1&keywords=usb+audio+mixer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J5XS3C)

I have been looking up videos on using it/using mixers in general. I know a little bit about sound design, studio mixers are a little foreign to me but I've been quickly picking up on the way they work (mostly just trying to figure out the different inputs/outputs and knobs).

So what I think my setup would be like is this..

**1.)** Send my XLR mic to the input on channel 1. Obviously.
**2.)** Send the PS4 audio to the 3/4 Channel input. The PS4 will output audio through it's optical out, then I have a Toslink to Stereo converter to get the L/R audio to put in the mixer.
**3.)** Then I get a little lost. I want to send JUST the microphone to the PS4 (which only takes microphone through USB), and be able to mute/unmute at will. So would I send the audio to the PS4 through the FX Send (using a 1/4"-USB)? I would turn the FX nob all the way down on the 3/4 channel so that the audio from the PS4 doesn't end up going back into itself, at least that's what it seems like in my head.
**4.)** Then to get everything to my PC I guess I could just send it out through the Main Out into my PC?

Just looking for a little direction, I am willing to look into other mixers as well, but this one is well priced and seems to have everything I need, with a few more inputs for if I wanted to add a few more inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan looks alright. Regarding #3 - if you want to mute the microphone signal for only the PS4 you use the FX send knob, and if you want to mute it completely simply use the mute button.

About the PS4 connection - you can use either a small ["USB To Headphone"](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/usb-stereo-audio-adapter) sound adapter like this one:

[image: Mini USB to Headphone Sound Adapter]

or a special split cable/adapter (3.5mm TRRS to TRS Audio & Mic Splitter) like this one:

[image: 3.5mm TRRS to TRS Audio & Mic Splitter]

No matter which option you go for, you should be careful with the FX send volume as it goes to a microphone input on the PS4.

Here is a video going through the setup for both options:

Comment: Thanks! This is the confirmation I needed. For sending the sound to the PS4 I was going to use [this](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VM8M4NK?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_3&smid=A2AN59XOQCTDYD). Is there an advantage to using the "USB to Headphone" adapter that you mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure really - if you already use the build in connector for something else I guess.